# Joining two tables in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I have two tables verse and thought. Im using Laravel 4.2
display the verses it is not listed in thoughts

[image]

my want the output sample1 and sample 2

Comment: Maybe because Verses 1 and 2 are not active in the thought table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
thought.*
, verse.verse
FROM
verse
LEFT JOIN thought 
ON (verse.`id` = thought.`id`);
```

Comment: This question being tagged Laravel-4, I assume the question was seeking an answer using Laravel's ORM rather than a plain query.

Comment: $verses = Verse::lists('reference', 'id') ->join('thoughts', function($join){$join->on('verses.id', '=', 'thoughts.verses_id')             })->get();